# Firefox on Protractor launching but not running

Tags: javascript, firefox, protractor, geckodriver

I'm sorry for my newbism but I need your help to understand something about Protractor and Geckodriver.

I'm using Protractor with Webstorm (for IDE). I want to run my e2e tests on Firefox but this one is launching but not running my tests.
Firefox's opened but always a blank page.
I tried to run a webdriver-manager update & start but not successfull.
To execute, I run "ng serve" to run my local project and I use the run-tool in webstorm (that exec protractor protractor.conf.js)

I'm using Protractor v5.2.0, geckodriver v0.19.1, Firefox v52.5.2.
This is my protractor.conf.js :

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/Users/mnotheber/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe"]
  },

  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [
    {'browserName': 'firefox', 'moz:firefoxOptions': {'args': ['--safe-mode']} }
  ],
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

I need your help and if you want more information, ask me.

Comment: Try directConnect: true instead of standalone option. Please try & let us know, it should work.

Comment: @tyaga001 not working for me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to update Firefox to latest v57 as gecko driver 0.19.0+ supports only firefox 55+ 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.19.0

Answer (score -1):

try by updating your webdriver-manager module using **webdriver-manager update**.
If still now working then you can also try **directConnect: true** option in conf file.

Comment: I tried both and nothing better. It's very weird because Firefox launched but didn't run my e2e tests...